# How do I set an Icon to a JButton without losing the animation when it's pressed?

Tags: java, swing, animation, icons, jbutton

I have created a custom button icon using an online tool, and then I have downloaded the .png file.
I have already set the icon in the JButton (Swing Application), but, when the button is pressed, it doesn't show the regular animation when a button is clicked.
Is it possible to set an Icon without losing this effect?
Thanks (here's the code)

```
public final JButton SEARCH = new JButton();
SEARCH.setBorder(null);
SEARCH.setContentAreaFilled(false);

ImageIcon searchb = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("search.png"));
SEARCH.setIcon(searchb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different icons (images) based on your requirement.
that means you have to use another image which resemblance pressed button using your original image

see below

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setPressedIcon(); // shows when button is pressed 
b.setSelectedIcon(); // shows when button is selected(applicable for toggle buttons) 
b.setDisabledIcon(); // shows when button is disabled 
b.setRolloverIcon(); // shows when mouse pointer hovering on the button
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the speed in replying.
I'll try your method immediately. Have a nice day!

Comment: All suggested methods take an `Icon` as an argument

Answer (score 0):

You may disable lines `setBorder(null); setContentAreaFilled(false);` in order to enjoy the default animation. The animation stays, and the image is over it.

```java
public final JButton SEARCH = new JButton();
//SEARCH.setBorder(null);
//SEARCH.setContentAreaFilled(false);

ImageIcon searchb = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("search.png"));
SEARCH.setIcon(searchb);
```